# Redirect requests from an old website in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have built a website for a client using ASP.Net MVC 3, which was built to replace an old site that I did not build and was written in PHP.

Most of the pages I have on the new website map to an old one from the original, such as www.mysite.com/contactus used to be www.mysite.com/contactus.php

After reviewing my error logs (recorded by Elmah) I am getting errors for requests to some of the old pages, like this:

The controller for path '/ContactUs.php' was not found or does not implement IController.

Does anyone have a reccommendation on how to correct this issue, ideally to redirect the user to the new destination if it exists or perpahs just to default them to the home page.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this with an IIS rewrite rule in your web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove .php suffix">
      <match url="^(.*).php$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This should strip the '.php' suffix on any incoming request. See here for more information: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 2):

You can use this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "oldphp",
    url: "{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "PhpRedirect", action="Get" },
    constraints: new { path = @".*\.php" });
```

And then implement `PhpRedirectController` like this:

```
public class PhpRedirectController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(string path)
    {
        // TryGetNewUrl should be implemented to perform the
        // mapping, or return null is there is none.
        string newUrl = TryGetNewUrl(path);
        if (newUrl == null)
        {
            // 404 not found
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
        else
        {
            // 301 moved permanently
            return RedirectPermanent(newUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AntP: I've updated my answer so that it works in that case as well.